# Caching and lazy loading from images Android

Tags: android, image, caching, lazy-loading, universal-image-loader

I have been searching on the web to find a good caching and lazy loading images from internet on Android, but it seems all the libraries uses some widget (like listviews, galleries, grids, etc...) to work like [Universal Image Loading](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

What i need to do, is to load an array of url's strings in the background while one image is shown in a ImageView widget, when the user clicks a button, the next image of the array should appear in the same ImageView widget. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at RestDroid? https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid

Comment: After reading  your second paragraph again, that is going to be somewhat custom.  You can preload the image in the background, but having it appear on cue will be the job of your custom view.

Comment: I only need the image caching and loading, not the REST api

Comment: Take a look at Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Yes, picasso was the answer. Thank you @47.5